# Vertex of a parabola

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I compile this file:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
    \draw[thick] ({-sqrt(3)/2-1/2},{-1/2+sqrt(3)/2}) parabola bend (0,0)
      ({sqrt(3)/2-1/2},{1/2+sqrt(3)/2});
    \draw (0,0)--({sqrt(3)-1},{1/sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)});
    \draw (0,0)--({-(1/2+sqrt(3)/2)/sqrt(3)},{1/2+sqrt(3)/2});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

then I get this:
 [image]

Those two line segments are orthogonal and have a common point, which is (0,0). It can then be clearly seen that the vertex of the parabola is located *near* (0,0), but not exactly there. Can anybody tell me why? Wasn't the `bend` command meant to impose that the vertex is located at (0,0)? Could this be due to a rounding error?

**Note:** I am *not* asking for another way of getting this parabola, without the `parabola` command. I know how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without further ado, the parabola construction yields an "upright" parabola. In more detail, a "standard" parabola is given by

```
p(x) = a x^2 + b x + c ,
```

and if you supply three points, `(x_1,y_1)`, `(x_2,y_2)` and `(x_3,y_3)`, then Ti*k*Z will find the coefficients `a`, `b` and `c` by solving

```
p(x_i) = y_i  for i=1,2,3.
```

However, if you want the tangent at `(0,0)` to have a nontrivial slope, you seem to be looking for a rotated parabola. So you may want to use the `rotate` key. Your parabola is equivalent to

```
\draw[thick] (165:{sqrt(2)}) parabola bend (0,0) (75:{sqrt(2)});
```

but you seem to want

```
\draw[thick,rotate=30] (135:{sqrt(2)}) parabola bend (0,0) (45:{sqrt(2)});
```

which goes through the same three points but isn't "deformed".

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
%     Your parabola
%     \draw[thick] ({-sqrt(3)/2-1/2},{-1/2+sqrt(3)/2}) parabola bend (0,0)
%       ({sqrt(3)/2-1/2},{1/2+sqrt(3)/2});
%     Alternative presentation of your parabola
%     \draw[thick] (165:{sqrt(2)}) parabola bend (0,0)
%       (75:{sqrt(2)});
%   You may want
    \draw[thick,rotate=30] (135:{sqrt(2)}) parabola bend (0,0)
      (45:{sqrt(2)});
    \draw[rotate=30] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0);
%     \draw (0,0)--({sqrt(3)-1},{1/sqrt(3)*(sqrt(3)-1)});
%     \draw (0,0)--({-(1/2+sqrt(3)/2)/sqrt(3)},{1/2+sqrt(3)/2});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very clear answer!